# Always call static constructor

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, static

Is there a way of calling the constructor of a static class always? After searching, I've seen that it is call only once.

I have a class with many methods, mine is like 20 methods, but let's imagine the class has 500 methods.
These 500 methods have all of them a call to a webservice.
Now, before the call to the webservice I have to do a security check with certificates (due to changes in servers):

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
```

So I have to write that code before each call.
All the methods are static, as well as the class, so my options are:

- Copy and paste the code in all 500 methods (will create a method to encapsulate the two lines).
- Convert the static class into instantiate class, and put the code in the constructor, but I will have to change the rest of the code to create objects of this new class, disposing it...

Is there a way to call the static construcor always? I've seen something about Aspects, but not really sure how to use them.

Comment: A static dictionary will be called once. You can't call it like a normal constructor.

Comment: You should use a lamba expression, in which you will encapsulate these two lines, and then run whatever you have to run later on. My 2 cents.

Comment: I would recommend to use a better design architecture. . . Using a static constructor for your requirement is a very unwise idea. . . . .

Comment: Your first option should do it, write an `validateCredentials`-method where you put your two lines and call it in every method you need it. Static constructor is definitely not goof idea here

Comment: But copying and pasting 500 times the same call to a new method in each method... I just though there could be another choice :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` constructors are meant to run only once. You are not going to change that.

The best solution is, as you stated, to create an instance of your class and put that code that needs to be ran again in the constructor. It seems to me though that certificate checks need to be done once, since the certificate won't change in a few seconds.

Comment: I will probably create instance of the class then. The problem I think, is that external code have to be change and you can't change it. Although this  is not my case, fortunately.

Comment: The certificates are checked here, and in another classes. The checks are a little different, and to different servers. That is why we need to call that code again each time (in case it changed).

Comment: Not really, if there is no "simple" solution for this :(

Answer (score 2):

No

A [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) can only be called once and is intended only for initialization, not for logic (such as authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Singleton` instance of the class instead of either instantiated or static class instance.

You get the power of the instantiated class but can use it like a static class meaning your issue with repetitive code is resolved and you can use it like a static class in that your single instance is available as a static property.

[Implementing Singleton in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

yIf you would like to perform a security check, I would suggest the use of [Singleton](http://www.dofactory.com/net/singleton-design-pattern) pattern. You can make a security check at tthe private constructor, but **be aware that this this will be ridiculously wrong**.

It will only make security check for the first call, then will reside in memory and won't necessarily perform a security check for other calls.

Comment: Static classes can have a static constructor.

Comment: Static classed do not have instances, not even one.

Comment: @juharr, true. Meant to something else, but expressed it completely wrong. Corrected.

Comment: If I create Singleton pattern, the class can't be static, doesn't it? So, I will have to change all the "external" calls to first create the object : class = new class();

Comment: Not it is inddeed static. Singleton pattern insures single instance of a class. Instance property holds the static instance of the class.